# How do I disable a "pycodestyle" warning inside a python code?

Tags: python, pycodestyle

I need to disable a warning of a `pycodestyle` check within a python code snippet.

How to do that?

Comment: You should show the snippet and say what warning is raised. Maybe the `#noqa` comment over the offending line could help.

Comment: the `# noqa` comment on the offending line does not help.

Comment: You should add the code and warning. It could help others to propose solutions...

Comment: I did not try to post an answer... What I meant is that I do not know any generic way to silence a pycodestyle warning, but I know that some specific warning can be silenced at the file level. As I did not know whether it was relevant here, I just asked for details. And honestly, as you got no answers in 1 hour and only my comment, I also hoped that those details could help others, that would know pycodstyle better than I do, to post answers. Said differently I was just trying to help you the best I could...

Comment: I did not know that only specific warning can be silenced. Thanks for that information!

I want to silence the W503 warning `Line break occurred before a binary operator`